If $G$ is a group with a finite index normal subgroup $N$, must we have $N\cong G$ or $G=NH$ for some finite subgroup $H$?
The answer to the titular question is obviously "no", consider $$
G = \mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb Z / 2\mathbb{Z})
$$
has a normal subgroup $N=(2\mathbb{Z})\times \{0\}$ which is neither isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ nor a factor of an internal semidirect product. However, $N\cong\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}$ and $G$ can be built from a product of $\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}$ with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. One can build similar examples in the same way: Say that $N$ is a special normal subgroup of $G$ if it is finite-index one of the following holds:

$G = NH$ for some finite $H$ a subgroup of $G$.
$G \cong N$
$N$ is a special normal subgroup of $N'$ and $N'$ is a special normal subgroup of $G$.

For example: The group $N=(2\mathbb{Z}\times \{0\})$ is a special normal subgroup of $G=\mathbb{Z}\times (\mathbb Z / 2\mathbb{Z})$ because $N$ is a special normal subgroup of $N'=\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}$ by condition 2, which in turn is a special normal subgroup $G$ by condition 1, therefore condition 3 implies that $N$ is a special normal subgroup of $G$.
Update: Actually, in my context I am primarily interested in whether $G=NH$ rather than specifically $G=N\rtimes H$. That makes the question only interesting for infinite groups.
Is every finite-index normal subgroup of $G$ a special normal subgroup?

How can you define special-ness in terms of itself (item 3)?

$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is a finite index normal subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, but the latter is neither isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ nor isomorphic to a semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ by anything.

Your title says "finite", your post says "finite index". Which is it?

finite index! sorry!

Isn't $2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ a counterexample?

I suppose that it is! If you post as an answer, I'll accept.

@Randall It's called a recursive definition.

@DerekHolt Recursive definitions typically need to define a base case and a way of indexing the recursion towards that base case. As written, it seems that the definition "A special normal subgroup is any finite-index subgroup" would satisfy the properties stated.

The base case would be $N=G$ and the index would be the index of $N$ in $G$.

Please do not rely on the title of your MSE questions for important information that is not in the body of the question. Referring to the "titular question" is definitely not on.

I think the whole thing can be phrased better as "there is a subnormal chain $N=N_0\triangleleft N_1\triangleleft\cdots\triangleleft N_k=G$ such that for each $i$, $0\leq i\lt k$, either $N_i\cong N_{i+1}$, or there exists a finite subgroup $H$ such that $N_iH=N_{i+1}$."

It is known that if $F$ is a free group of rank $n$, and $H$ is a subgroup of index $k$, then $H$ is free of rank $1+k(n-1)$. This is the Nielsen-Schreier formula.
Let $F$ be free of rank $2$ generated by $x$ and $y$, and let $N$ be the normal closure of the subgroup generated by $x^3$ and $y$ (i.e., the kernel of the surjection onto the cyclic group of order $3$ generated by $x$). Then $N$ has index $3$ in $F$, so $N$ is free of rank $1+3(1) = 4$. In particular, $N$ is not isomorphic to $F$. In addition, no nontrivial subgroup of $F$ is finite, so there does not exist a finite subgroup $H$ of $F$ such that $F=NH$.
Moreover, because the index of $N$ is $3$, there do not exist proper subgroups $N'$ of $F$ that properly contain $N$. Thus, $N$ also cannot satisfy clause $3$: if there is a normal subgroup $N'$ of $F$ with $N\leq N'\leq F$, then either $N'=N$, in which case $N'$ is not special in $F$; or $N'=F$, in which case $N$ is not special in $N'$. Thus, $N$ is not "special" in $F$, despite being normal and of finite index.

Nothing special about $F$ being rank $2$ and $N$ index $3$, other than $F$ being nonabelian and the index being prime. If $F$ is of rank $n\gt 1$ and $N$ is of prime index $p$, then the rank of $N$ if $1+p(n-1)$, which cannot equal $n$ (since $1+p(n-1) = n$ requires $n=1$ or $p=1$).

Is the phrase "Let $F$ be free abelian of rank 2" a typo? Seems like you just want it to be free of rank 2?

@MartianInvader Yes; "abelian" does not belong. Fixed.
